# Declare some land national forest

Tags: united-states, ownership

Many have heard of the [Tree that Owns Itself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_That_Owns_Itself) in Athens, Ga.

According to the Wikipedia article "Such a deed, even if it did exist, would have no legal standing."  So my question is, could I donate land to the national forest so it would essentially never be owned?

Comment: At a minimum, you'd need the Forest Service to agree to accept the land. In some cases, I believe expanding a national forest, or creating a new one, might require an executive order or act of Congress. Anyway, the land wouldn't own itself; it would be owned by the federal government.

Comment: Secretary of the Treasury (and heir to the Mellon fortune) Andrew Mellon bequeathed land and money to help form many national parks, most famously the Cape Hatteras National Seashore in North Carolina.  It helps to be rich and a member of Cabinet!.  It's a fascinating sequence: Congress passed acts that created the park in 1936, but it didn't become formally established until Mellon's grant of money and 28000+ acres in 1957.  http://www.nps.gov/parkhistory/online_books/caha/caha_ah.pdf